# Savon: WCF Soap service with wsse auth: AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: ruby, wcf, soap, savon

I am trying to create SOAPClient using Savon - rubygem.

Its a WCF soap service with WSSE auth over https. Here is the code that I tried:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new do
    wsdl.document = "https://svc.sxxxxxify.com:8081/ConfSet.svc?wsdl"
    config.soap_version = 2
    wsse.credentials "aa5@xxasxsaxsh.com", "test123"
end

p client.wsdl.soap_actions
response = client.request :get_user_clients
p response
```

But I get this error:

> http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault2012-10-26T06:07:42.247Z2012-10-26T06:12:42.247Zs:Sendera:DestinationUnreachableThe message with To '' cannot be processed at the
>   receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
>   Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses
>   agree.

.

> The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an
>   AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the
>   sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree. (Savon::SOAP::Fault)

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Does savon support WS-A. How do I pass TO using savon for ws-addressing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem. I've solved the 'To' problem by providing a header entry and a new namespace. The 'Action' header was also necessary though, and I only discovered that after inspecting SoapUI logs. Here is what worked for me:

```
  @service_url = 'https://svc.sxxxxxify.com:8081/ConfSet.svc/service'
  @action = 'your_action'
  @client = Savon.client(:wsdl => "#{@service_url}?wsdl", :soap_version => 2, 
    :namespaces => {"xmlns:x" => "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"}, 
    :soap_header => {"x:To" => @service_url, "x:Action" => "http://tempuri.org/#{@action}"})
```